# genexus trying to get started and getting "error: GeneXus Account (20): "Please sign the GeneXus Prototyping Cloud Terms and Conditions in order "

Tags: genexus

Followed the Travel Agency tutorial to the point of created the Customer Transition and screen and hit F5.

Then get

```
error: GeneXus Account (20): "Please sign the GeneXus Prototyping Cloud Terms and Conditions in order to deploy your application. Http://www.genexus.com/my-apps". (Read more...)
Failed: GeneXus Cloud Request
```

Followed the link after signing in and tried again, same error.

Update, tried starting over with new account/email and got the same error on hitting F5 at the point after creating the customer.

I clicked the 'Acceptar' Thinking that was how to "sign" but did not read the 'not interested'

So how do I fix?

I was hoping to finish the tutorials but am blocked now.  How can I start over other than creating a new account with a different email?

Comment: I would suggest asking the kind folks at GeneXus ... to explain *how* you are supposed to get their servers to understand that you >have< signed the T&Cs.   (Or maybe click on the "read more" link to see what it says.)

Answer (score 0):

Although the 'Acceptar' button was next to test that said I am not interested in current hosted applications, I took that to mean not wanting to host on Amazon, and especially since it said in the text that by simply intalling and using you accepted.

So I clicked 'Acceptar' and was back in business.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in prototyping in the cloud with GeneXus, you should do the following:

- If you already have a GeneXus account, you just need to go to the
  menu Tools / GeneXus Account and enter your username and password
  there.
- If you do not have an account, you can create one at
  https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/sign-in

If you are not interested in prototyping in the GeneXus cloud, you should change the property of the model at the level of the Generator you are using and set

Deploy to Cloud = **NO**

and specify to which platform you will deploy and press F5